# Xrm.Utility.openWebResource() error page not found

Tags: crm

I add a button (ribbon workbench).and add him a command - open a web resource.
I wrote:
`Xrm.Utility.openWebResource("new_my_webresource");`
but when i click on the button - i get an error :

> "the page not found".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open web resource in another window in CRM online 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715900/open-web-resource-in-another-window-in-crm-online-2015)

Comment: Why do you ask new question instead of continuing initial discussion - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715900/open-web-resource-in-another-window-in-crm-online-2015/34716823#34716823